# Installing php-css-parser without composer

Tags: php, css, git, composer-php, autoloader

I would like to use php-css-parser (https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser) in a website project.  I do not have access to the back end terminal.  The Git page provides basic instructions for installing the library with Composer.  How can I install the php-css-parser library without shell access?  Ideally, I would like to just ftp the files to the site directory and edit the files with a php editor if necessary.

If it is of any help, I can use cURL from a *.php file.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its core, Composer is just downloading a bunch of source code into the `vendor` directory and generating `vendor/autoload.php` for you. You can do this all on your local machine, then FTP the `vendor` directory up to your server.

Comment: What would the autoload.php look like?  Would it be a bunch of require_once statements?  And then the autoloader.php is a require_once in the index.php file of my project?

Comment: No, it's not a bunch of require statements (although it does use them), and you don't really have to care about the autoloader's details. All you'd do in your app is `require_once('vendor/autoload.php');` and let Composer's loader handle the rest.